# set_mode() in pygame asks for a positional argument and I don't know what to do

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to do Snake to exercise and ran into this problem when I run the game:

`TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'`

I tried to fix it many times, It is strange tough because I'm following a tutorial and the guy in the video doesn't have such a problem.

This is the whole code, it's not finished yet, also sorry if I did any grammatical mistakes, I'm not a native speaker.

````
import pygame

def main():
    global rows, width, s
    width = 500
    rows = 20
    win = pygame.display.set_mode(size=(width, width))
    s = snake((0,255,0), (10,10))
    flag = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        clock.tick(10)
        s.move()
        redrawWindow(win)

#Serpente-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class snake(object):
    body = []
    turns = {}

    def __init__(self, color, pos):
      self.color = color
      self.head = cube(pos)
      self.body.append(self.head)
      self.dirnx = 0
      self.dirny = 1

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            for key in keys:
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    self.dirnx = -1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.dirnx = 1
                    self.dirny = 0
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = -1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

                elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.dirnx = 0
                    self.dirny = 1
                    self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]

        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            p = c.pos[:]
            if p in self.turns:
                turn = self.turns[p]
                c.move(turn[0], turn[1])
                if i == len(self.body)-1:
                    self.turns.pop(p)
            else:
                if c.dirnx == -1 and c.pos[0] <= 0:
                    c.pos = (c.rows-1, c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirnx == 1 and c.pos[0] >= c.rows-1:
                    c.pos = (0, c.pos[1])
                elif c.dirny == 1 and c.pos[1] >= c.rows-1:
                    c.pos = (c.pos[0], 0)
                elif c.dirny == -1 and c.pos[1] <= 0:
                    c.pos = (c.pos[0], c.rows-1)
                else:
                    c.move(c.dirnx, c.dirny)

    def reset(self, pos):
        pass

    def addCube(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, surface):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.body):
            if i == 0:
                c.draw(surface, True)
            else:
                c.draw(surface)

class cube(object):
    rows = 20
    w = 500
    def __init__(self, start, dirnx=1, dirny=0, color=(0,255,0)):
      self.pos = start
      self.dirnx = 1
      self.dirny = 0
      self.color = color

    def move(self, dirnx, dirny):
        self.dirnx = dirnx
        self.dirny = dirny
        self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.dirnx, self.pos[1] + self.dirny)

    def draw(self, surface, eyes=False):
        dis = self.w // self.rows
        i = self.pos[0]
        j = self.pos[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (i*dis+j, j*dis+1, dis-2, dis-2))


#Resto----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width, s
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    s.draw()
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()
    

def drawGrid(w, rows, surface):
    sizeBtwn = w // rows

    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(rows):
        x = x + sizeBtwn
        y = y + sizeBtwn

        pygame.draw.line(surface, (20,20,20), (x,0), (x,w))
        pygame.draw.line(surface, (20,20,20), (0,y), (w,y))

main()```

Also sorry if I did any grammatical mistakes, I'm not a native speaker.
````

Comment: Can I know if you have added ```import pygame``` syntax to the code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably has something to do with the fact that you didn't import pygame at the beginning of your program. Simply try adding `import pygame` in the first line. If you still get the same error, you can go check out how to [download pygame](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't show in the code above, but I already downloaded Pygame in VSCode and imported it. I know it because it worked before, but it suddendly stopped to work.

Comment: OH, i just noticed it's a problem related to "pylint", but I don't even know what it is, how do i solve it in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I don't know what is the problem yet, but I recommend you ask that in a separate question. You'll have better chances to get a reply!

Comment: Thanks, i was gonna try and look for it on the internet, and maybe find another thread, thanks for helping a newbie like me!

Answer (score 0):

The method requires the surface (screen) parameter.

Try:

```
def redrawWindow(surface):
    global rows, width, s
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    s.draw(surface)    # <<< pass surface to method
    drawGrid(width, rows, surface)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Ok I did and i guess it worked but i suddendly get this problem:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`
I ran an example and it worked so why it doesn't find pygame?

Comment: @GGberry covered it. Add `import pygame` to the top of the script.